# Current Navigation/Left Navigation Display Issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, quick-launch, current-navigation

I have a SharePoint 2013 site which has multiple subsites in it. The existing subsites have the quick launch showing on each of the page. I have created new subsite and for this new subsite the current navigation is not showing up. All the subsites are inheriting the same custom master page from the parent site. I have enabled quick launch navigation for the new subsite, but not sure what exactly is happening.

In the DOM explorer, i could see that for the subsite which i have created, the style
 .ms-fullscreenmode #sideNavBox {
    display: none;
}

is being displayed again the corev15.css file. But I am not overriding anywhere these styles.

Thank You

Comment: What site template did you choose when creating the new subsite?

Comment: It is a team site

Answer (score 0):

Go to sub site->Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Master page->make sure you choose the same master page as parent.

Go to sub site->Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Navigation->Choose show subsites/show pages:

[image]

Comment: Hello Lisa, Already all these setting are in place. Still it is not showing up.